# Can ElasticSearch perform multiple aggregations with different query conditions in a single request?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am looking for a solution to get aggregations, one of each field, but apply different query conditions at different aggregations.

I have a collection of products, which has attributes: `type`, `color`, `brand`. 
User selected: `brand`=*Gap*, `color`=*White*, and `type`=*Sandal*. To display the counts of the various similar products of at each aggregation:

- Query condition for `brand` aggregation : `color`=*White*, and `type`=*Sandal*
- Query condition for `color` aggregation: `brand`=*Gap*, and 
  `type`=*Sandal*
- Query condition for `type` aggregation: `brand`=*Gap*, and `color`=*White*

Can this be done in a single ElasticSearch query?

Answer (score 4):

You'd create three aggregations with a `filter` agg for each and add the queries you'd like in there. I used the simplest one - `bool` with `term` - just to show the high level approach:

```
  "aggs": {
    "brand_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "color": "white"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "sandal"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "color_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "brand": "gap"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "sandal"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "type_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "color": "white"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "brand": "gap"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: If this answer helped you, marking it as accepted should help others when searching for similar queries.